# Excel VBA Run-time error 13 Type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

i get a runtime error 13 during compilation. this is the line that throws up an

error, y = Application.counta(("A:A") <> "" - 3). I tried declaring y as a variant/ () didn't help either. could anyone please point out where i am making a mistake, that would be very helpful.

```
Option Explicit


Sub Test()

' z= no of rows(temp calc sheet emp id)
' x= no of columns(dashboard calender)
' y= no of rows(dashboard emp id)


Dim i, j, k, d, x, y, z As Long
Dim Empid As Long
Dim currentdate, startdate, enddate As Date
'Dim countA As Long

startdate = Worksheets("Temp calc").Range("C2")
enddate = Worksheets("Temp calc").Range("D2")

x = (Range("n2") - Range("n1"))
y = Application.counta(("A:A") <> "" - 3)
z = Worksheets("Temp Calc").counta(("A:A") - 1)

For i = 1 To y  'To loop through the emp_id in dashboard.

For j = 1 To x Step 1 'To loop through the calender in dashboard daywise.

For k = 1 To z 'To loop through the emp_id i temp calc sheet.



        d = 0
        Empid = Cells(4, i)
        currentdate = Cells(3, 17 + j)

        If (Cells(k, 1)) = Empid Then
        If (currentdate > startdate) & (currentdate < enddate) Then     'To check whether the first column date falls within the project start and end date

        d = d + 1

        startdate = startdate + 1
        enddate = enddate + 1

        Cells(i + 3, j + 16) = d

End If
End If

Next
Next
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: `COUNTA` is used to count non-blank cells in a range, but you appear to be adding a condition `<>""` to it - `COUNTA` only accepts a range. Did you intend to use `COUNTIF`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to count non-blank cells in column A and subtract 3 from this number then try:

`y = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) - 3`

Comment: it worked but returned the same error for z how do i frame it for since i want to refer to col A in sheet "temp calc".

Comment: Try `Z = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Temp Calc").Range("A:A")) - 1`

Comment: yes it worked but i get the same error for 
am i not declaring something ?

If (currentdate > startdate) & (currentdate < enddate) Then